# Why my app crashes when I put the recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I followed a guide on youtube where it helps me to do a RecyclerView in Java but I'm a beginner.. so the compiler says that's ok but it crashes and I don't know why. Here is the page of my code about recycler view.

in Homepage.java :

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;
Toolbar toolbar;

private AppCompatButton getstart, augurio;

//istanzio recyclerview
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
//fine istanziata

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

    //Per il buongiorno con silente
    ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic__365678_fb_facebook_facebook_logo_icon, "Line1", "Line2"));
    exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic__365678_fb_facebook_facebook_logo_icon, "Line1", "Line2"));
    exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic__365678_fb_facebook_facebook_logo_icon, "Line1", "Line2"));

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewBuongiorno);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(exampleList);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    //fine buongiorno silente
```

then in ExampleAdapter.java :

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;

public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView mImageView;
    public TextView mTextView1, mTextView2;

    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Imageview);
        mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
    }
}

public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList){
    mExampleList = exampleList;
}

@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
    ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    return evh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);
    holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getmImageResource());
    holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getmText1());
    holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getmText2());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mExampleList.size();
}
```

}

then finally the last page java ExampleItem.java :

```
public class ExampleItem {
private int mImageResource;
private String mText1;
private String mText2;

public ExampleItem(int imageResource, String text1, String text2){
    mImageResource = imageResource;
    mText1 = text1;
    mText2 = text2;
}

public int getmImageResource(){
    return mImageResource;
}

public String getmText1(){
    return mText1;
}

public String getmText2(){
    return mText2;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show the full error log?

Comment: https://ibb.co/xh7qqkL <-- do you mean logcat?

Comment: You should filter log with your app instead of no filter. In `No debuggable process`, you select your app with `package name` defined in your manifest.

Comment: https://it.imgbb.com/ here it is

Comment: https://ibb.co/vcyHzjy <-- SORRY man, I found this error. Could you help me?

Comment: May I ask you to show content of the activity_home_page.xml?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zszUfPjf <-- Vlad this is xml you requested..

Comment: Thank you. Also, show me please all imports of the HomePage

Comment: Did you  solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, it was an error about the layout .. I've got a layout basic and a layout v29 and it crashes to me because in the version v29 I didn't put the recycler view in the file xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` and also `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in XML file which is not considerable. When you set setHasFixedSize(true) then you can not change the height and width of the the RecyclerView.

So, please remove `mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` or set the height of the recyclerView as a **match_parent**.

Comment: Thank you for notify me this error that I made.